# How do I include dynamic URLs in flask-sitemap?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using [Flask-sitemap](https://flask-sitemap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I can create a sitemap but the sitemap only includes my static pages.

How do I get my dynamically generated URLs into the sitemap?

Example of how I dynamically generate URLs:

```
@app.route('/blogs/<url>') 
def post_blog(url):
    row = Post.query.filter_by(url=url).first_or_404()
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For each entry point add this template:

```
#once
ext = Sitemap(app=app)

@ext.register_generator
def post_blog():
    yield 'post_blog', {'params': 'value'}, now, 'never', 0.7
```

> yield loc, {?params=value}, lastmod, changefreq, priority 0.0 to 1.0
> https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html